# will_paginate with ajax is working in one page but not in other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate with ajax.
I do it like that:

```html
@requests = Model.paginate(per_page: 20, page: params[:page])
```

```html
<%= will_paginate @requests %>
```

and in js:

```html
$(document).on("click","#requests th a, #requests .pagination a", function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

This one works fine. 
BUT when i use the same method for other page:

```html
@requests = SomeOtherModel.paginate(per_page:2, page: params[:page])
```

and put will_paginate inside view.
But pagination is not working.

POSSIBLE PROBLEM:
In first case I use pagination for request model, inside requests_controller. (and i have request resource defined).
But in the second case I am in closed_requests view page, whose action is inside the request_controller.

1st case hrefs on paginated links:

```html
/?page=2
```

(before click)

after clicking on pagination links hrefs loook like that

```html
/?_=1433158161065&amp;page=2
```

In the 2nd case:

```html
/requests/closed_requests?page=2
```

I suspect that link is builded wrongly. It is not consistent with the first.